# How to create a URL between two servers in a Blazor solution?

Tags: c#, routes, blazor, path-finding

I am fairly new to C# and Blazor and I was wondering what the best practice is to build a url between two serverin a Blazor solution.

I have two server in one solution. Server 1 needs a url as a string to a file that is in the same solution but in a different server.

For example

```
| SOLUTION

--| folder 1

----| folder 2

------| MyServerONE.Server

--------| myclass.cs --> Needs a proper link to my file which is on another server
  
--| folder 1

----| folder 2

------| MyServerTWO.Server

--------| myfile.xml
```

I tried to create a normal string with

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

and creating a relative path to the server